# Jpg images turn black on using cp command line

Tags: files, desktop-background, cp, jpeg

I have used the following command to copy folder containing JPEG and PNG images:

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/wallpap/ /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

However the JPEG images turn black while the PNG images are just fine. How do I avoid it?

Comment: Does this happen if you copy the files elsewhere (using cp and something else), or use the cp command directly on a file? (e.g. `sudo cp ~/Downloads/wallpap/file.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds/` ). Also what version of ubuntu are u using?

Comment: It happens only when the destination is outside my home directory. I am using **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the files permissions are not correctly set. Run the following to reset permissions to default (644 for files and 755 for directories):

```
sudo find /usr/share/backgrounds/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
sudo find /usr/share/backgrounds/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are copying as the root user (`sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/wallpap/ /usr/share/backgrounds/`)

then you'll have to change the permissions:

```
 sudo chown -R username /usr/share/backgrounds/wallpap/
```

Hope this'll help you